# Multi Touch and Isolate Area

Tags: c#, wpf

I have designed a Window in WPF that has 2 web browser controls. Each one has its own scroll bar. Touch events work for scrolling until I want to scroll them at same time.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
  <DockPanel x:Name="DockLeft"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <WebBrowser></WebBrowser>
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel x:Name="DockLeft"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <WebBrowser></WebBrowser>
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

How it is possible to have two isolated areas for touch event?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override Touch event on both WebControls(in event you have access to finger motions etc..) and provide custom logic there. Should be little work, but it should be ok.

Comment: i am beginner in touch UI , Can u Give me Sample?